# Canadian places identification

Tags: canada, identify-this

I've recently came across a post claiming that the following images are taken in Canada. A quick Google search told me that the first image is Spirit Island and the last is Moraine Lake. Third image was once (further images reuploads failed) identified as
Cass Scenic Railroad State Park. Are those accurate findings? These places look gorgeous.

Spirit Island (identified by Google, [map location](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Spirit+Island/@52.6431112,-117.4943952,17z/)):

[image: Spirit Island]

Moraine Lake (identified by Google, [map location](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Moraine+Lake/@51.3215642,-116.1936966,15z/)):

[image: Moraine Lake]

Cass Scenic Railroad State Park (identified by Google, [map location](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Cass+Scenic+Railroad+State+Park/@38.1864981,-79.1673194,857460m/), but not of exactly this place):

[image: Cass Scenic Railroad State Park]

Google failed to identify these two images:

[image]

[image]

Can someone confirm or otherwise name the locations?

Comment: The last one seem awfully generic and has no real identifying landmarks besides pine trees and a river. I'm sure I could find you something here in Colorado that looks just like it.

Comment: The state park will certainly not be in Canada.  We have no states.  But scenes like these are visible throughout the Canadian Rockies.

Comment: I've seen places that look like the last one in Northern Ontario, with no mountains anywhere. I don't believe the third one is in West Virginia, the trees are wrong.

Comment: @Dennis The mountains are also wrong for West Virginia.

Comment: @JimMacKenzie the picture isn't likely to be of the identified state park, however, which is in West Virginia.  West Virginia doesn't look much like that picture.

Comment: When people edit and approve edits, can they make sure that the edit doesnt harm existing upvoted questions please.

Comment: Edit rolled back as it harmed the combination of question and answers.

Answer (score 4):

Number 3 Looks like Morant's Curve near Lake Louise.  See http://www.artcountrycanada.com/jacquiard-max-the-canadian-at-morants-curve.htm for a classic painting of this scene, and https://banffandbeyond.com/morants-curve-the-famous-spot-along-the-canadian-pacific-railway/ for directions to the site.

Number 4 is Pyramid Lake, 52.924229, -118.096711.  It is just north of Jasper, AB.  https://www.instagram.com/p/Bp7OCo0BKwA/ for a winter version of the footbridge to the island.

Number 5 is very hard to find as the background has been obscured by the sun.  It looks like anywhere/everywhere along the Banff/Jasper Bow River or Athabasca River corridor.  I would need either a mountain or man-made structure to positively identify it.  This guess is based on the colour, water's edge, path, and general vegetation.  The Bow River itself can get that high on the bank but it is usually brown and very fast running then with spring run off when it is.  The smaller lakes often have a more green tint then the larger lakes and water here looks blue and most lakes are too small to have the wave that is visible in the photo.

I don't have the reputation to add the photos and I had to make a new account to edit this answer.

Comment: You can use the [Contact Us](/contact) form to have your accounts merged.